# Why is it faster to swim under water than on the surface?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, drag, surface-tension

In competitive swimming, swimmers are allowed to swim first 15 meters completely submerged, and it seems that they can swim much faster that way than if they swim on the surface.

I've seen several explanations on the Internet, some mention surface tension near the water-air boundary, some mention more turbulence, some mention wave drag. But they never elaborate, so it felt unsatisfactory. In addition, it feels that when you swim on the surface you should experience a bit less drag because a large area of your back is contacting with air rather than water.

Is there some quantitative explanation of this phenomenon?

Comment: I don't think this answer can be meaningfully approached without experiment, since the shape, motion, and initial velocity of a swimmer on the surface and the shape, motion, and initial velocity of a submerged swimmer are completely different. No answer identifying a particular factor, however correct the physics behind how **that factor** influences the outcome, can be any better than a guess that that particular factor dominates the difference between two very different phenomena.

Comment: Strange. My experience & training for competitive swimming in my youth is 100% the opposite of this hypothesis (i.e., that it is far *slower* to swim underwater than above it). I imagine that the air density being >500x smaller than water's density would provide sufficiently less drag on your arms moving in air than in water, hence being faster on the surface.

Comment: Breathing might have something to do with it

Comment: The same question can be asked for submarines and more readily answered (easier shape, less moving parts...^^). cf. e.g. https://navalpost.com/submarine-cavitation-drag-underwater-speed/

Answer (score 4):

The energy that goes into creating a wake with high surface waves is not available for propulsion.

My reasoning is as follows: I expect that at the surface a larger proportion of the work done (by the swimmer) goes to energy of the wake motion.

When the swimmer is sufficiently deep below the surface the water that surrounds the swimmer is closer to equal water pressure along the long axis of the swimmer. I expect that that will result in a more symmetric flow of water around the swimmer.

By contrast, at the surface the pressure distribution is the most uneven, allowing formation of surface waves.

See also:
Article titled: [The science of underwater swimming: how staying submerged gives Olympians the winning edge](https://theconversation.com/the-science-of-underwater-swimming-how-staying-submerged-gives-olympians-the-winning-edge-163721) Author: [Anthony Blazevich](https://theconversation.com/profiles/anthony-blazevich-285090) Professor of Biomechanics, Edith Cowan University

Quote:

> The breaststroke event was the cause of major controversy in the 1956 Melbourne Olympic Games as swimmers experimented with staying underwater for much of their races. The winner of the men’s 200-metre event, Masaru Furukawa of Japan, swam underwater for most of the first three laps of the four-lap race. This practice was swiftly outlawed after the games; swimmers were forced to surface before they could start to swim.

The breaststroke loses to the other strokes because the breaststroke swimming posture creates the largest waves. Hence the adapted breaststroke, (adapted towards optimization for submerged swimming), gave the submerged swimmers a significant advantage

Interestingly, Blazevich mentions that for the other three strokes remaining submerged only became a net win when swimmers became good at swimming in a dolphin-like manner. That manner of propulsion is described as 'Dolphin kick'. I infer that without a sufficiently well executed dolphinkick swimming submerged is not a net advantage (for backstroke, butterfly stroke, and fastest stroke).

Comment: This answer would be better with citations from sports medicine that have actually looked at the fluid dynamics of the human swimmer. Literature search "biomechanics of swimming" or similar.